# ScriptApp.newTrigger().forForm Issue

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers, google-forms

I am attempting to create a Google Form that when fed a different Google Form URL, it would create an onFormSubmit() trigger for the given form url.

```js
function createFormSubmitTrigger(e) {
  var formResponse = e.response;
  var itemResponses = formResponse.getItemResponses();
  var url = itemResponses[0].getResponse();
  var formCopy = FormApp.openByUrl(url);

  ScriptApp.newTrigger('onFormSubmit').forForm(formCopy).onFormSubmit().create();
}
```

When I log the details of formCopy, it is definitely retrieving the details of the correct given form. And yet, the only triggers getting created are for the Google Form that is accepting the URLs

[Triggers Description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t2f9v.png)

Am I understanding TriggerBuilder incorrectly? Is this some sort of bug?

Comment: An interesting question. I think the problem is that ScriptApp is only able to write triggers in its own script. One thing you might try though, is using openbyid rather than openbyurl. OpenbyURL is buggier.

Comment: It's a bug, unless your code is installed as an add-on.  An add-on is restricted to only creating one trigger of each type for the file in which the add-on is used.  [Add-on triggers - restrictions](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/concepts/triggers#restrictions_2)  But if it's not an add-on then your code should be able to install a trigger into another Form as long as you have permission to do that.  If it's a Form owned by a different account, then you can't, by default, add a trigger to a Form that you don't own.  That would be a security issue.

Comment: Ah understood, thank you! This seems like overkill for what I'm trying to do. Hopefully Google Apps Script will fix this bug so that it at least errors out when attempting to add a trigger to a form you aren't authorized to access...

Comment: Try `ScriptApp.newTrigger('onFormSubmit').forForm(formCopy.getId()).onFormSubmit().create();` and see if there's a difference.